# Having trouble with regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to construct a regular expression which parses mentions. e.g.

```
@aaa @bbb@ccc @dddd @eeee
```

it should match only **aaa**, **dddd** and **eeee** but not **bbb@ccc**

I have tried the following regular expression but it fails:

```
/(?:^|\s)@(\S+)/g
```

an example can be found here:
https://regexr.com/3h9o5

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1171/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RE doesn't match because of \S. \S match @ too, so you need to replace it for what a name should be. Your RE should be something like

```
/(?:^|\s)@([^@\s]+)/g
```

Here it will match just 'aa' from '@aa@'. If you want whitespaces after the name you should use

```
/(?:^|\s)@([^@\s]+)(?=\s|$)/g
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex with `\B` and negated character class:

```
\B@([^@\s]+)(?=\s|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rLj8ID/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\B`: assert position where `\b` does not match
- `[^@\s]+`: Match 1 or more characters that are not `@` and not a whitespace
- `(?=\s|$)`: Lookahead to assert that we have whitespace or end of line at next position

Comment: Thanks it works. But I am still not sure how \B works

Comment: I checked the pattern again. It fails here: https://regex101.com/r/7UH5K7/1

Comment: You can use: `(?:^|\s)@([^@\s]+)(?=\s|$)`